# Exporting data from R that is in a list generated by a function

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export, export-to-csv

So I've used the decompose function and I want to export all the lists it generates not just the plot it creates. I tried converting the lists into either a matrix or data frame but then that gets rid of the date header and year columns so if someone knows how to convert it and keep the list formatting that would solve my issue I think.

Anyway, The closest I've got to being able to do this keeping the list format is by doing

```
capture.output(decompose, file = "filename.csv")
```

As you can see from the image attached though:

[image]

Sometimes the months arent all together in a row which is really not helpful or what I want. It also just puts it in one column and I'm having to go into the excel after and do the text to column option which is going to get old really quickly.

Any help would be greatly appriciated. I'm really new to R so apologise if there is an obvious fix I'm missing.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the data? Where are you going to import it? The JSON format might be suited.

Comment: Some code with examples would help.

Comment: I want to use in in power Bi. most functions just turn the data shown above into a list of all the values. Basically i need a way to convert decompose$seasonal output into a matrix or dataframe that keeps the dimensions above, the years and the months or I need to generate an image of the list to show in Bi